# Replace string inside tag using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to use regex to replace `<p ....>` by '' and `</p>` by `<br>`:

```
<p style="text-align:center;">1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...<\p>
```

I tried:

```
re.sub("[\<\[].*?[\\>\\]]", '' '', x)
```

but it erased everything.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You have an extra `]` at the end of your regex

Comment: <\/*p.*?> match 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

One option could be to use a capturing group to get the text out of the tag, then add a `<br>` to the end:

```
pat = re.compile(r'<p[^>]*>(.*)<\\p>')  # or </p>, as required

print(" {}<br>".format(pat.match(x).group(1)))
# 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...<br>
```

Or you could do two replacements

```
pat1 = re.compile(r'<p[^>]*>')
pat2 = re.compile(r'<\\p>')

pat1.sub(' ', pat2.sub('<br>', x))
# 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...<br>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should never use regexes for XML/HTML. XML is good at nesting tags, and nested tags are a nightmare for regexes. You should go with lxml of BeautifoulSoup here.

That being said, for very simple use cases, regexes can do the jobs, **provided you can make sure that no nesting can occur**.

Assuming that you have (note the **/p** instead of **\p**):

```
x = '<p style="text-align:center;">1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...</p>'
```

you can use:

```
>>> re.sub(r'<p.*?>(.*?)</p>', r'\1<br/>', x)
'1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...<br/>'
```